# How to disable iptables logging without removing the rule

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iptables, rsyslog

Can I disable the iptables logging without removing the  `--log-prefix "iptables: "` rule?

I have added the following rules into the iptables:

```
iptables -A INPUT -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables: " --log-level 7
```

And then configured the rsyslog with this file:

/etc/rsyslog.d/10-iptables.conf

```
:msg, contains, "iptables: " -/var/log/iptables.log
```

After restarting the system, iptables can log to the /var/log/iptables.log as expected.

**Now, I want to implement this function:**

I want to stop the iptables from writing any logs to the real file, including kern.log, dmesg, /var/log/iptables.log, etc.

But I don't want to change the already configured iptables rules.

Is there any other rsyslog configuration can be used for `discarding all iptables log without changing any iptables rules`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `& stop` at the end of your `/etc/rsyslog.d/10-iptables.conf`